# Pandas resample data by a non-timeseries column (e.g. Price)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Renko Chart Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renko_chart

I'm trying to generate a renko chart using the trade tick data. The tick data contains Timestamp, Price, Volume. The Timestamp is in unix milliseconds format. e.g. 1649289600174.

Pandas already supports OHLC resampling via `df.resample('10Min').agg({'Price': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'})`. However, I would like resample trade data based on **price**. Not by Timestamp.

Renko chart utilises a fixed brick size. For example, a brick_size of 10 would generate a brick if the price goes up 10 points, or go down 10 points.

I have been told by a pandas contributor that this can be done via `groupby with a binned grouper`. However, I don't quite understand what he is talking about.

This is how my original data looks like.

```
Timestamp           Price               Volume

1649289600174       100                 100
1649289600176       105                 100
1649289600178       110                 100
1649289600179       104                 100
1649289600181       101                 100
1649289600182       100                 100
1649289600183       103                 100
1649289600184       107                 100
1649289600185       102                 100
1649289600186        99                 100
1649289600188        93                 100
1649289600189        90                 100
1649289600192        95                 100
1649289600193       100                 100
1649289600194       105                 100
1649289600195       110                 100
1649289600196       115                 100
1649289600197       120                 100
```

I'm looking for an option that looks like, `df.resample('10Numeric').agg({'Price': 'ohlc', 'volume': 'sum'})`. Here `10Numeric` says, the brick_size is 10. If the price goes up 10 points, or go down 10 points, then I would like to aggregate the data within that period.

The output should look like

```
Timestamp           Open    High    Low    Close               Volume
    
1649289600178       100     110     100     110                 300
1649289600182       110     110     100     100                 300
1649289600189       100     107      90      90                 600
1649289600193        90     100      90     100                 200
1649289600195       100     110     100     110                 200
1649289600197       110     120     110     120                 200
```

I believe the pandas contributor talking about pd.cut option. And then do groupby.
Something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': np.random.randint(1, 100, 1000)})
df['bins'] = pd.cut(x=df['price'], bins=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60,
                                          70, 80, 90, 100])
```

That output looks like this.

```
      price       bins
0       92  (90, 100]
1       15   (10, 20]
2       54   (50, 60]
3       55   (50, 60]
4       72   (70, 80]
..     ...        ...
95      88   (80, 90]
96      21   (20, 30]
97      91  (90, 100]
98      51   (50, 60]
99      18   (10, 20]
```

Please note: Price data is not unique. The price of bitcoin one year back would have looked like 45555 USD. But it's again at the same price this year. If I use a 100 bin size, it would be in (45500, 45600).

A groupby would put both 1 year ago data and current data at the same bin. I'm looking for a solution that follows the price movement. e.g. The closing prices should look like this `45500, 45600, 45700, 45600, 45500, 45400, 45300, 45200, 45100, 45000`

Can someone explain what the pandas contributor mean when he says, `groupby with a binned grouper`?

Comment: why is that the expected outcome? `ohlc` would give you 4 columns. please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ignoring_gravity I don't think you understood my question. Or I misunderstood your comment.   I'm aware `ohlc` would give me 4 columns. But I'm trying to resample the data by price. Not by timestamp. There is no option exists in `df.resample()`  to resample the data by price. So my issue is not with the `ohlc` part, but with the resampling part. Thanks

Comment: sure, but if you resample by a timestamp and do `ohlc`, then you'll get 4 columns. wouldn't you want 4 columns when resampling by price as well?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Yes, I want 4 columns when resampling by price. My main question is how can I resample the data by price? Thanks

Comment: For a start, when you write "The output should look like", show what the output should actually look like

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Updated the question with the output I'm expecting. I'm looking for a standard OHLC columns, but resampled by price. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new column based on `pd.cut`, do a `cumsum`, and group by that.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600174, "Price": 100, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600176, "Price": 105, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600178, "Price": 110, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600179, "Price": 104, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600181, "Price": 101, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600182, "Price": 100, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600183, "Price": 103, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600184, "Price": 107, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600185, "Price": 102, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600186, "Price": 99, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600188, "Price": 93, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600189, "Price": 90, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600192, "Price": 95, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600193, "Price": 100, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600194, "Price": 105, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600195, "Price": 110, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600196, "Price": 115, "Volume": 100},
        {"Timestamp": 1649289600197, "Price": 120, "Volume": 100},
    ]
)
codes = pd.cut(df["Price"], bins=np.arange(0, 200, 10), right=False).cat.codes
df.groupby((codes != codes.shift(1)).cumsum()).agg(
    {"Price": "ohlc", "Volume": "sum", "Timestamp": "min"}
)
```

This'll give you:

```
  Price                 Volume      Timestamp
   open high  low close Volume      Timestamp
1   100  105  100   105    200  1649289600174
2   110  110  110   110    100  1649289600178
3   104  107  100   102    600  1649289600179
4    99   99   90    95    400  1649289600186
5   100  105  100   105    200  1649289600193
6   110  115  110   115    200  1649289600195
7   120  120  120   120    100  1649289600197
```

Comment: This is brilliant.  Thanks a bunch. Could you tell me why you are using `0, 200, 10`?  There will be billions of rows. I don't want to set a hard limit.

Comment: The second line seem like flawed. `2   110  110  110   110    100  1649289600178`. Open, Close, High, Low, all has a value of 110. Also the 7th line.

Comment: I think bins should use `range(df['Price'].min(), df['Price'].max(), 10)` just like BeRT2me.

Comment: yeah, something like `range(df['Price'].min(), df['Price'].max(), 10)` would be better

Comment: Why is the second line flawed? The only row in that brick (i.e. `[110, 120)`) is the one with timestamp `1649289600178`

Comment: If all 4 price points are the same, it is neither a candle nor a brick.  So I would prefer ohlc that are not the same.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the data we have and not with your code.

Comment: I just tested your code with 1 million rows. Definitely something is wrong with the code. When I used a python loop to generate the bricks, I generated around 255 rows with a value of `brick_size=75`. But when I generated the bricks using your code with `pd.cut(df["price"], bins=np.arange(0, df['price'].max(), 75.00), right=False).cat.codes`, I see 6161 rows. That is not normal. Thanks

Comment: perhaps show your python loop then?

Comment: I use mplfinance library.  I have posted my code here. https://gist.github.com/dsstex/8c4430e0e2455624958267a09ab8e71a

Comment: where's your Python loop?

Comment: I have cloned the mplfinance module just to have high and low values since mplfinance doesn't support it. I don't want to reproduce the entire mplfinance code here since it is way too long.  This is the function I customized. https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/src/mplfinance/_utils.py#L774  So when I mean python loop, I'm talking about the for loops found in that function.  I have list called prices. My code appends all the prices during that window. And then I'm doing `high = max(prices)` to find the high price. `low = min(prices)` to find the low price.

Comment: You can see the close price over here. `brick_values == close_prices`. 
 https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/src/mplfinance/_utils.py#L917

Comment: I also have this line at line 915.  This is a custom code I added to have open prices. `open_values.append(curr_price)`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df['bins'] = pd.cut(x=df['Price'], bins=range(df['Price'].min(), df['Price'].max(), 10))
df.groupby('bins').agg({'Price': 'ohlc', 'Volume': 'sum'})
```

Output:

```
           Price                 Volume
            open high  low close Volume
bins                                   
(90, 100]    100  100   93   100    600
(100, 110]   105  110  101   110    900
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have tested your code. I'm not seeing the down movement. Here is the output. https://gist.github.com/dsstex/1f8efae915640990d31bd2a3d726ae6b  As you can see the bins are in increasing order and I don't see any duplicate bins. A correct output in my case would have duplicate bins.  For example `45500, 45600, 45700, 45600, 45500, 45400, 45300, 45200, 45100, 45000` prices has `45600` twice. One during upmove and one during downmove. Your code only produces bins for the upmove. I hope I'm not missing something here. Thanks very much.